# Loading related data AspNet Core 1.1

Tags: entity-framework

I am developping a web site to learn AspNetCore.
I use AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles tables,

I started with Vs2015 and ASpNet.Core 1.1 and I achieve to retrieve the list of roles and the numbers of users associated to each role with this code

```
    model = roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleListViewModel
    {
        RoleName = r.Name,
        Id = r.Id,
        Description = r.Descricao,
        NumberOfUsers = r.Users.Count
    }).ToList();
```

Today I downloaded the final release of VisualStudio 2017 Community, and when I lunch the web app, I have an error to retrieve the list of roles,

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: No value provided for required parameter '_outer_Id'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.CreateCommand(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> parameterValues)
```

The problem now, seems to be NumberOfUsers = **r.Users.Coun**t

What do I need to change in my code to work?

Comment: This is a known bug. (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7811) Should be fixed in 1.1.2

Comment: Thanks Alaa Masoud, to point me the correct information. 
It's pretty boring now I have to stop waiting for version 1.1.2.

Comment: You can use 1.1.0 where this bug does not exist. It regressed in 1.1.1.